# Что я сделал не так когда переопределил обработчик исключений? (DRF) Ошибка 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Может не так прописан путь к файлу? Подскажите пожалуйста.

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'json_auth_project.exceptions.core_exception_handler',
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': 'error',
}
```

**exceptions.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def core_exception_handler(exc, context):

    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    handlers = {
        'ValidationError': _handle_generic_error
    }

    exception_class = exc.__class__.__name__

    if exception_class in handlers:
        return handlers[exception_class](exc, context, response)
    return response


def _handle_generic_error(exc, context, response):
    response.data = {
        'errors': response.data
    }
```

Специально ввожу некорректные данные чтобы проверить исключение, но получаю ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Структура**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]